# NATS-streaming - Where i can find clusterID? I watched tons of websites, but there's nowhere i could find how to know it

Tags: windows, go, nats.io, nats-streaming-server

I'm moved to golang, so i started to research about base technologies. I found Nats streaming, downloaded some packages via command line(choco). And then after typing nats-streaming in cmd, i got some answer from it that it started, BUT TO CONNECT IN GOLANG I NEED clusterID, AND I HAVE NO IDEA WHERE TO FIND IT(((

I used to write custom configs, but it didn't worked. Also i typed smth like "info"(i don't really remember what it was, but the fact is that it didn't work)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i searched for NATS-streaming, but in fact downloaded NATS server, that have no -cid command. For all who will research same problem, you should download NATS-streaming from github